# Swift xcode 7 get wifi security type

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, wifi

Is there anyway to detect if the wifi connected is secured using swift and xcode 7? is it possible to get the type security on the wifi? wpa, wep etc

This is for iphone

Comment: Sorry my bad, this is for iphone